# Long lived plant identification

Tags: identification, perennials, sedum

This plant has been alive for at least 25 years. I know this for sure, because it was here when my parents moved into this house when I was born. No one knows what it is. It has pink clusters of flowers when it blooms, not sure what time of year. Any ideas? From searching Google, I'm thinking some kind of Sedum? 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sedum spectabile - there's more than one pink variety, and one with darker more reddish flowers called 'Autumn Joy'. It's an herbaceous perennial, hardy, and the flowers are popular with some butterflies. Common name Ice plant [(Sedum spectabile)](http://www.wildaboutgardens.org.uk/plants/container-plant/sedum-spectabile.aspx).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I always called it "that glazed looking plant".

Comment: Sedums are very cool.  If you ever want to multiply/grow more, they are ridiculously easy to grow from cuttings.  I've even had decent success with autumn joy sedum by just cutting a whole stem off at the base, removing the bottom couple leaves and just sticking it into soil.